# Strange behavior in python if/in word in file check

Tags: python

Python isn't showing output when runned the above code, while expected "truth". Any help?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class login:

   def login():

      Smith = John

      users = open("names.txt","r")

      if "Smith" in users :
         print("truth")
      else:
         print("false")
```

Content of names.txt:

Smith

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

`open` returns a file object, not a string. You can read the contents of the file using the `read()` method, something like this:

```
with open("names.txt", "r") as fin:
    users = fin.read()

if "Smith" in users:
    print("truth")
else:
    print("false")
```

*Edit:*

If nothing is happening when you run your program, and if the code you posted is your whole source file, then you are not running the method you have defined.

A `def` inside a `class` block will define a method belonging to that class. You don't actually seem to be using the class though. If you just want to define the `login()` function and run it, you can do that like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def login(): # <-- this only defines the function
    with open("names.txt", "r") as fin:
        users = fin.read()
    if "Smith" in users:
        print("truth")
    else:
        print("false")

login() # <-- this actually runs the function you have defined
```

Comment: same behavior, after run python file.py, returns immediately to prompt command with no message

Comment: Are you actually running the method, or only defining it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a context manager to open your files, you also cannot just use `in user.read()` as you will get False positives matching a substring like `foo in foobar`.

You can use a regex with a word boundary for an exact match with `any`  evaluating line by line lazily iterating over the file object getting a line at a time without reading the whole file at once:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r"\bSmith\b")
with open("names.txt", "r") as user:
      if any(r.search(line) in line for line in users):
         print("truth")
      else:
         print("false")
```

If each line is a name by itself you could rstrip and compare each line:

```
with open("names.txt", "r") as user:
      name = "Smith"
      if any(line.rstrip() == name in line for line in users):
         print("truth")
      else:
         print("false")
```